# DatePickerDialog result back to Fragment?

Tags: android, datepicker, fragment, fragmentmanager, samsung-galaxy

I want to get the selected Date from the DatePickerDialog back to my Fragment.
Whe i test it, i only get in the Build Log this Error:
**E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null**

Testing my code on an Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge (7.0)

The Dialog appears, i can choose a date, click on ok but dont get the result to my TextView... Did i forget a little detail??

*My Fragment where i call the DatePickerDialog:*

```html
package at.marcelklein.drautaxi;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Marcel on 10.09.2017.
 */

public class FourthFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    View myView;
    TextView textView;
    Button btnDayStart, btnDayEnd;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fourth_layout, container, false);

        btnDayStart = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.button_daystart);
        btnDayEnd = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.button_dayend);
        textView = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.textView12);

        btnDayStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                datePicker.show(ft, "datepicker");
            }
        });

        btnDayEnd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //showDialog();
            }
        });


        return myView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        String currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(c.getTime());
        textView.setText(currentDateString);
    }





}
```

*DatePickerDialog Fragment:*

```html
package at.marcelklein.drautaxi;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSet;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), onDateSet, year, month, day);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign your fragment as a listener. Add it as listener like this

```
btnDayStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.onDateSet = FourthFragment.this
            FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            datePicker.show(ft, "datepicker");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I implement the Listener at (public class FourthFragment extends Fragment **implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener**). Your suggestion (datePicker.onDateSet = FourthFragment.this) didnt work :(

Comment: what is the error. You will need to make onDateSet public in DatePickerFragment

Comment: If i hit Run, it tells me:
cannot find symbol variable onDateSet in "FourthFragment"

datePicker. **onDateSet** = FourthFragment.this;
onDateSet is red marked... 

In the DatePickerFragment.class i set this:
public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener onDateSet;

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to this: **DatePickerDialog**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment  implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
    tv.setText("Gewähltes Datum:");
    tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\nJahr: " + year);
    tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\nMonat: " + df.format(month));
    tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\nTag: " + df.format(day));
}
```

----------- And my **Fragment** where i call the **DatePickerDialog**:

```
public class FourthFragment extends Fragment {

View myView;
public TextView textView;
Button btnDayStart, btnDayEnd;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fourth_layout, container, false);
    btnDayStart = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.button_daystart);
    btnDayEnd = (Button) myView.findViewById(R.id.button_dayend);
    textView = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.textView12);

    btnDayStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
            datePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), "date Picker");
        }
    });

    return myView;
}
```

Now i change the TextView directly from the DatePickerDialog.
I think thats not the best Solution...

The think i want is a Range Date Picker like "TimeSquare DatePicker".
But i cant choose days from the past in "TimeSquare DatePicker".

Any suggestions?